# Convert Ontime App purchase to an Yearly Subscription

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an android app which is currently having one time purchase fee. Owing to the changes in Google Map API Subscription Policy, I need to change that to a subscription model (Annual Subscription).

Is there an option to convert the One time pricing to a subscription model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can convert it to Weekly, Monthly, 3 Months, 6 Months, Annually and Seasonal.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions) is the official documentation and [Here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en) are steps to implement it.

When you change it to annually, documentation says the time will be counted from date of purchase, and all the conditions for new and past users. Read it carefully and implement it as per.

The documentation on Billing is mentioned [Here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api).
Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, I could not find the option in the developer console to convert the one-time payment to an annual subscription. Should i need to publish a new one?

If I could convert the same, it would be really helpful. Thank you